# How do I animate influence of follow path

Tags: animation

I Have been using blender to make/modify objects for 3D printing and now I thought I would try some animation.

I am trying to start the camera moving along a path starting at frame 40.  From frame 1 to 40 it moves via key frames with loc.  Starting at frame 40 I would like the camera to follow a circle path for a couple of iterations.

How do start / stop the influence of the path at specific frames.

I in my googling have seen mention of a start/stop but I am not seeing in properties/constraints.  I see noting to control the constraint in the dope sheet or the NLA editor. (Which I just discovered)

[image]

Comment: You can animate the influence slider at the bottom of the constraint.. (hover over it and press I to insert keyframes). Is that what you want?

Comment: Ok, that helps.  Now where does/should that gem exist in the wiki?  I see the influence animating but the camera does not move sigh.

Comment: There are so many reasons that might happen.. Here's a .blend with it working: http://www.pasteall.org/blend/31333 As for the wiki, see the many pages on animation: http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Animation

Comment: The reason was too much experimenting...  I fixed it by removing and adding a new camera.  Now how do I actually delete the old messy camera from the blend file?, do not answer here... I will ask a new Q if I cannot figure it out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can be done by animating the influence slider at the bottom the the constraint.

Most interface elements in blender can be keyframed by pressing <kbd>I</kbd> while hovering over them.

[image]