# Clone Animation to Controller Rig?

Tags: animation, rigging, keyframes, constraints

I have a tool that exports animations to blender, but those animation keyframes are applied directly to the rig.

I have a better rig setup with constraints and a controller rig. The controller bones are not 1:1 to the actual rigs bones.

The problem is that the animations doesn't "do" anything while the constraints are on, because the controller bones aren't moving. Disabling the constraints allows the animation to play.

Is there a way to temporarily "reverse" the constraints so that the controllers are moved as necessary in each keyframe according to the animation.

Then I would need to turn the constraints back on so I could use the controller to modify the animation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, the contrstraint's infuence is also animatable. Just move your mouse cursor above the influence slider and hit "i". https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15476/how-do-i-animate-influence-of-follow-path

Comment: Not ideal as I'd rather have the controllers moved according to the bone's actual position in that keyframe.

If that's not doable, is there at least a piece of python script I could run for each constraint  to key it? I have many keyframes and constraints, manually keying every one for each frame isn't feasible.